# FireDac get asBytes is giving wrong values

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I'm trying to read a blob field from an SQLite table using FireDac in Delphi 10.3 Rio. when I call this line of code:

```
var bytes:TBytes;
begin
bytes:=FdTable.fieldByName('Field').asBytes;
end;
```

I get the wrong bytes, as it is in the wrong encoding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `FdTable.FieldByName('Field').DataType` and `FdTable.FieldByName('Field').ClassName`? You should also show us how do you create DB schema (i.e. `CREATE TABLE ...`).

Comment: the field is simply a blob field, the scheme of the database has nothing , when i view the value of this field in an sqlite browser i get different bytes from delphi

Comment: You have provided insufficient information to fully diagnose the issue. We really need [mcve] to help you. Until then we can only guess. My guess is that the field of TFDTable is created as `TWideMemoField` or `TWideStringField`, because the column's [data type affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples) in underlying SQLite table **is not** `BLOB`.

Comment: yes the field is treated as TwideMemo where it is simply a BLOB field.

Comment: the problem is read bytes should read bytes not a string and give correspondant bytes according to the default encoding ?